# sorting numbers with firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I'm storing a score for each player of my game in firebase.

```
 scores {
     name,
     score
 }
```

I want to sort the scores by highest to lowest.

This is what I'm trying

```
 let highestScore = firebase.database().ref('scores').orderByChild('/score');
 highestScore.on('value', getData, (err) => console.log(err));
```

This is how the database is setup

[image]

How can I sort the scores by highest to lowest?

Thank you.

Edit:

This post got be banned from asking questions :( what can I change from it?

Comment: can you please add your firebase node structure and some data samples

Comment: I added some more code and the db structure

Comment: Please also add `getData`. Have a look at [How to create a minimal, complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which is the most efficient way to ask for help.

Comment: I added getData

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firebase Database always returns results in ascending order. That means you'll need to reverse the results in your client-side code. With your current structure, that means you can implement `getData` as:

```
function getData(snapshot) {
  var scores = [];
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    scores.unshift(childSnapshot.val());
  });
  console.log(scores);
}
```

This will show the scores in descending order, since [`Array.unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) adds the item to the start of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Do as follows if you want to get the ranking only once:

```
    let highestScore = db.ref('scores').orderByChild('score');
    highestScore.once('value', function (snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
            var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
            console.log(childKey);
            var childData = childSnapshot.val();
            console.log(childData);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try one of the suggested functions in the documentation: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sort_data

```
orderByChild()  Order results by the value of a specified child key or nested child path.
orderByKey()    Order results by child keys.
orderByValue()  Order results by child values.
```